# Extracting behaviour from transformation

Tags: etl, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I have a couple of transformations that all do similar functionality before and after the actual ETL processing:

- Look in certain directories to see if new files for integration have appeared (directories maintained in database)
- Mark found files as "being used" in database (and store a couple of other file attributes)
- Move files to a "being used" sub-directory
- *Run ETL process*
- Mark files as "finished"
- Move files to a "finished" sub-directory

These steps are a business requirement and are 100% identical (apart from different database tables for the list of directories to search in and files registered) for each ETL process based on file input. Maintaining X copies of this near identical process (and updating *all* of them if it has to be changed seems non-ideal)

So, I have created a "skeleton" transformation that does all this and has the "Run ETL process" part "injected" by getting passed a variable to the location of a transformation. This way the "injected" transformation does not need to know of the file handling steps and the file handling steps are decoupled from actual ETL processes.

Since I am fairly unexperienced with PDI I was wondering how problems like these are usually solved and if my approach is any good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach conforms to best practice. Moving processed files in an archive directory is the way to go, and keeping the status "In use"/"Finished" in a database accessible from outside is quite convenient.

*Traditionally* you would have defined the file name and other attributes in [parameters](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.0/Products/Data_Integration/Data_Integration_Perspective/050) on the transformation rather than in a database. However, to store them in a database allows you to access it from outside and even to make a small web app just to display the status.

You can also extract the pre- and post-processing ETL in separate transformation and orchestrate the whole process in a job.

I suppose you did not forgot to include the file size (number of rows) among the couple of other attributes. And that you have a naming convention to help you re-run the process in case of failure without headache.

And finally, I suggest you also keep track of the logs in the database. Just click anywhere, select `Properties`/`Parameters`/`Transformation`, define a `database connection`+`table`, an `logging interval` of 2 (seconds), and press the `SQL` button.
All what you see in the bottom `Step metrics` table (Input, Output,...) will be kept in the database. Useful when you discover that something went wrong last week.

Comment: Just a quick follow up question: How do I properly generalize table names? Whenever I use variables in database-related steps everything works on execution, but in the (Spoon) editor I constantly get console errors about failing to look up the meta information of the previous rows.

Comment: Short answer: you cannot use the ? syntax on the from clause in SQL (java limitation on prepared statement). You may use the ${variable} syntax, like explained near the end of https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Table+Input. If you need more info, please open an other question, as editing comment in SOF is (on purpose) fairly limited.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing right. Guess you are using **Mapping step** to reuse the common parts of your transformations:

https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Mapping